# Adjust `prism.js` code snippet box width according to text width

Tags: javascript, html, css, prismjs

**My HTML is as follows:**

```html
<link href="https://snip-share.herokuapp.com/static/css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<pre><code class="language-Python line-numbers">import time

print(time.time())</code>
</pre>
<script src="https://snip-share.herokuapp.com/static/js/prism.js"></script>
```

**Output of above code:**

Output of above code => https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDSVQ.jpg

**Expected Output:**

Expected Output => https://i.stack.imgur.com/7esAU.png

Simply means I just want to set the black box width according to the text width inside it, so kindly suggest me any way to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the content with a container element and apply `display: inline-block` to it.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://snip-share.herokuapp.com/static/css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <pre><code class="language-Python line-numbers">import time

print(time.time())</code>
</pre>
</div>
<script src="https://snip-share.herokuapp.com/static/js/prism.js"></script>
```